# Data loss in Redis through jedis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

We are trying to insert values in Redis with the help of java client jedis-2.1.0.jar. We have two modules in our application. One uses `get` call throughout the day with around 2000 requests per second. Other module does the data loading (around 100 million) everyday when day starts (from 4am to 11am).

We have put logs for our calculation of the data. Our logs shows exact match with the input count, but when we check by redis-cli, we get lesser count. The difference range is around 250k to 2.5 million. Our machine has around 120G memory. Below is part of the code where we are trying to load data into Redis.

```
Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
int recordCount = 1;
while ((dataCurrentLine = dataFileBuffer.readLine()) != null)
{
    pipeline.multi();
    if (lineIndex == 1)
    {
        String[] tmpArr = dataCurrentLine.split(Constants.HYPHEN);
        recordCount = Integer.parseInt(tmpArr[1]);
        LOGGER.info("TotalRecords: " + recordCount);
    }
    else if (lineIndex < recordCount)
    {
        String[] dataArr = getRedisStorageData(dataCurrentLine);
        String msisdn = dataArr[0];
        String dataStr = dataArr[1];

        if (Utils.isNullOrEmpty(dataStr) == false)
        {
            if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled())
            {
                if (addedMsisdns.contains(Long.parseLong(msisdn)))
                    LOGGER.info("Duplicate MSISDN: " + msisdn + "|File: " + fileName);
            }

            addedMsisdns.add(Long.parseLong(msisdn));
            pipeline.set(msisdn, dataStr);
        }
        else
        {
            deletedMsisdns.add(Long.parseLong(msisdn));
            pipeline.del(msisdn);
        }
    }

    if (lineIndex % 100 == 0)
    {
        pipeline.exec();
        // printTmpStatus(1);
    }

    lineIndex++;
}
pipeline.exec();
pipeline.sync();

// printTmpStatus(0);
tmpList.add(fileName);
}
```

Our Redis version is

```
redis_version:2.8.6
```

Please let us know how to tackle this problem, as it is quite hard to check for each entry.

Comment: You are using the same Jedis instance and the same pipeline for each insertion. I think it is not correct, if you want to insert data 100 by 100, you should get a new Jedis instance from your JedisPool and building a new Pipeline instance on it. What happens if your Jedis instance timeouts or has a network problem?

Comment: You mean to say, after every 100 operations, I should get a fresh jedis instance and pipeline from it?
But if any timeout or a network problem occurred in-between, wouldn't jedis throw exception when I try to sync again with the same old connection?

Comment: If you get an exception, then try to get a new Jedis instance and pipeline and send the same data (which has not been sent successfully! It can be why you loose data). You will have a fallback which is good. Also you can't retry indefinitely, so you can add an exponential backoff policy above if needed. You don't have the same counts, so you miss data somewhere, and broken Jedis / pipeline can be the problem. Did you check logs for JedisException / TCP data loss?